# pass model value to href in image?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

My `Model` has image file name. I want apped to file name to href

```
@foreach (var images in Model)
{
    //href="~/ImageGallery/"@images.imgname 
    //which is href="~/ImageGallery/cat.jpg"
    <a href="~/ImageGallery/"  title="Banana" data-gallery>
        <img src="~/ImageGallery/thumbnails/" alt="Banana">
    </a>
}
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

like this:

```
@foreach (var images in Model)
      {

          <a href="~/ImageGallery/@(images.imgname)"  title="Banana" data-gallery>
          <img src="~/ImageGallery/thumbnails/" alt="Banana">
          </a>
      }
```

I will prefer you to use `Url.Content()` helper though the above chunk also works, but `@Url.Content()` generates the right url form the relative url:

```
@foreach (var images in Model)
          {

              <a href="@Url.Content("~/ImageGallery/"+images.imgname)"  title="Banana" data-gallery>
             <img src="~/ImageGallery/thumbnails/" alt="Banana">
              </a>
          }
```